# how to create unit test for jQuery change event

Tags: jquery, node.js, jestjs

I'm totally new to perform unit test for nodeJS app.
my app is created with NodeJS and Jest

would like to create unit test for the part dealing with $

```
'use strict';

const Postmonger = require('../js/postmonger');
var connection = new Postmonger.Session();

let authTokens = {};
let payload = {};

$(window).ready(onRender);

let validateEventCode = false;

$('#eventCode').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#eventCode').val() === ''){
    validateEventCode = false;
  } else {
    validateEventCode = true;
  }
});
```

any solution for above issue?